# Social Customer Service - Compute time taken for agent to respond

Tags: social-customer-service

Is there a trial version to try our Social Customer Service?

I'm looking to find out if we can implement SLA for social posts responses from our agents.  Basically trying to compute the "time taken for an Agent to respond to customer posts on Social media (fb, twitter)". (I will be using Social Studio as well, if needed)

Of course, I'm not looking for an entire solution, just would like to know if this is even possible. Can't seem to find about SLA in the feature list.

Answer (score 1):

We built a custom solution on top of the social Studio API. When a post is updated, workflow events are attached to it - whether you do so from withing Social Studio or from SCS.

We have a rule engine that cycles thru the events as they are added to determine whether they are SLA related and then calculate the used SLA / End of SLA (taking into account working hours/holidays etc.)

You need to be careful as some events will have a timestamp that is the actual event time, whereas others (such as when you add a label to a post) will have the timestamp of when the label was actually created which leads to errors.

SCS will add events but I'm not sure whether it can access all the events attached to the Social Post. In any case, do not trust the firstEngagement and latestEngagement field values that are populated in the Social Posts